# SQL decimal data type in mysql/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, types, phpmyadmin, decimal

when trying to create new Table/Column including decimal data type it auto change for example from decimal(9,3) to decimal(9). mysql/phpmyadmin Bug ? mysql version is 5.7.14
why ?

Comment: Well, yes, this does suggest a bug -- in your code.  But you don't show the code, so there is really nothing for anyone else to go by.

Comment: i'm using phpmyadmin to add the table structure :/ (graphical way no code yet :D )

Answer (score 0):

If you are really talking about the data, not the "datatype", ... If your number is "12,345" because it is some non-English Locale, then the parsing stops at the comma, and you get "12", which stores as "12.000" in `DECIMAL( ,3)`.

Comment: it store as 12 not 12.000 otherwise, when i define DECIMAL(9,3) it change automatically to DECIMAL(9) (if i write with sql not graphical way it's done correctly) (i think the problem with the input control ?)

Comment: Is it changing the _output_ or the _datatype_?

Comment: DataType from DECIMAL(9,3) to DECIMAL(9)

Comment: Please double check the punctuation used and the locale.  `(9.3)` turns into `(9,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in phpMyAdmin (I use version 4.6.4, while the latest stable version is 4.7.1):

1) Using raw SQL works fine:

> ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name`
>   DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL;

2) Using the UI to set Length/Values to 3,1 produces wrong SQL:

> ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` DECIMAL(3)
>   NOT NULL;

No difference if using . (dot) instead of , (comma).

**BE careful when using the phpMyAdmin UI for manipulation of table structures as you could easily truncate data! Always check with Preview SQL what is about to be executed!**